# Owl carousel 2 nagivation arrows on side

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I am currently using owl carousel to make a slide with pictures. 
But the problem now is, I wanna make the navigation on both side (not on top of the slide).

Below is my script:

```
$('.teamc').owlCarousel({
items: 4,
margin: 20,
autoHeight : true,
autoWidth: true,
center: true,
nav: true,
loop: true,
autoplay:true,
navText: ['<div class="customNextBtn" style="float:left; margin-left:33px"></div>', '<div class="customPreviousBtn" style="float:right; margin-right:33px"></div>'],
responsiveClass: true,
responsive: {
  0: {
    center: true,
    items: 1,
    margin: 20,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoWidth: true,
    nav: false,
    loop: true
  },
  600: {
    center: true,
    items: 4,
    margin: 20,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoWidth: true,
    nav: false,
    loop: true
  },
  1000: {
    center: true,
    items: 4,
    margin: 20,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoWidth: true,
    nav: true,
    loop: true
  }
}});
```

[Here is the sample picture of what I want it to be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfYuV.png)

Comment: go through https://codepen.io/peshoto/pen/yxewzg. This will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have this:

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    ...
 </div>
 <div class="owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-controls">
        <div class="custom-nav owl-nav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

you should add below code in js :

```
$('.main-content .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    .... ,
    navContainer: '.main-content .custom-nav',
    ....
});
```